# Help with the integral $\int \frac { x } { x + \tan x } \mathrm d x$

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

Help with the integral:

> $\int \frac { x } { x + \tan x }\mathrm d x$

My try follows: using identity $\tan(x)= \frac { \sin x} { \cos x }$   yields

$$\int \frac { x\cos x } { x\cos x + \sin x }\mathrm d x$$
Now what?

Comment: Neither Maple nor WolframAlpha produces a closed-form result.

Comment: from where Comes this integral?

Comment: see here http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+x%2F(x%2Btan(x))

Comment: The integrand has a singularity whenever $\tan x = -x$.  The first positive one is at $x=2.1$-ish.  The graph is interesting.  The limit at $x=0$ is $1/2$ and the limit at $x=\pi/2$ is $0$ (this is where $\tan x$ blows up.  Perhaps the original question asked for a definite integral, say from $0$ to $\pi/2$?